# I can't use the sorted function to sort a two elements tuple list in descending numerical order then in ascending alphabetical order in case of a tie

Tags: python, function, sorting, tuples

I used the sorted() function to sort a list of tuples, as it is shown below. the output is in descending order as wanted for the second elements (numbers). but what I really want is to sort the tuples in ascending alphabetical order in case of a tie.

Help please.

```
sorted(word_Count, key = itemgetter(1,0), reverse = True)
```

Output:

```
[('butter', 2), ('was', 1), ('the', 1), ('of', 1), ('but', 1),
('bought', 1), ('bitter', 1), ('bit', 1), ('betty', 1), ('a', 1)]
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `list.sort` twice, since, according to `list.sort`'s docstring, it is in place:

```
L.sort(cmp=None, key=None, reverse=False) -- stable sort *IN PLACE*;
```

So, to sort your list, you could do

```
>>> word_count.sort()
>>> word_count.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
>>> print(word_count)
[('butter', 2), ('a', 1), ('betty', 1), ('bit', 1), ('bitter', 1),
 ('bought', 1), ('but', 1), ('of', 1), ('the', 1), ('was', 1)]
```

Just make sure to sort alphabetically first, then sort by the second key after that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `sorted()` function along with [`lambda`](http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/lambda_functions.html) as:

```
>>> sorted(word_count, key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))
[('butter', 2), ('a', 1), ('betty', 1), ('bit', 1), ('bitter', 1), ('bought', 1), ('but', 1), ('of', 1), ('the', 1), ('was', 1)]
```

My `lambda` function is returning tuple as `(-x[1], x[0]))` which represents to sort the list in descending order of `x[1]` (`-` represents descending) and in case of match sort in the ascending order of `x[0]` (without `-` sign means ascending)

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot Sir. Do u have any useful doc about that function  please?

Comment: You may refer document: [Using Lambda Function](http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/lambda_functions.html)